# Facebook Analytics admin page does not load, it only shows a blank page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-analytics

I started to experience this issue since yesterday, and I am trying to confirm if it is a bug in the Facebook Analytics admin page. This is what I am doing:

1) Visit https://developers.facebook.com/ and login with my Facebook account.
2) In the top right area of the page, under "My Apps", I click on my app, and I see the following welcome/home screen:

[image: Facebook Developers admin screen]

3) I click the "View Analytics" link that appears in the top area (the header with the white background) of the image above. The new page opens in a new tab and it tries to load for a few seconds but then it stops, and this is all I see:

[image: Blank page, Facebook Analytics dashboard does not load]

I have not found people online complaining about this. I tried from different computers, web browsers, and operating systems, and I always get the same problem. From a phone or tablet I can access Facebook Analytics but the mobile version is limited and they even have a message encouraging people to use the desktop version.

It was working correctly for me yesterday morning and part of the afternoon. Any information about it?

Comment: After logging in with my Facebook account, if I try to visit directly this URL: https://www.facebook.com/analytics/, I am redirected to https://www.facebook.com/analytics/898765768798706/, and then I just see the blank page in the image shown in the body of this question. For privacy reasons, I made up the number "898765768798706", but what I get is a similar number with the ID of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now. I guess it was down for several hours but it is up and running again.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue of the facebook analytics page not loading for a very long time (https://www.facebook.com/analytics/28xx27xx15xxxxx/).

I guess the service was down for at-least an hour if not more. Once I reached home and refreshed the page, the analytics data was displayed.